# Как исправить ошибку на c#: Object не содержит определения Direction?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я тренировался писать шаблон Наблюдатель, выполняя задание: При помощи шаблона наблюдатель реализовать отправку сообщений  о нарушителях на посты ДПС. Каждый пост ДПС имеет список нарушителей. Пост также имеет направление на кортом ,он распологается(север, юг, восток. запад.)Если в ифнормации о нарушителе направление совпадает данный пост добавлет нарушителя в свой список.
Написал код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Lab6
{
    // Объект, за наблюдением которого будут следить посты ДПС
    class Violator
    {
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    // Интерфейс для наблюдателей
    interface IObserver
    {
        void Update(Violator violator);
    }

    // Пост ДПС, который будет получать сообщения о нарушителях
    class DpsPost : IObserver
    {
        public Dictionary<string, List<Violator>> violatorsByDirection =
            new Dictionary<string, List<Violator>>()
        {
        { "Север", new List<Violator>() },
        { "Юг", new List<Violator>() },
        { "Восток", new List<Violator>() },
        { "Запад", new List<Violator>() }
        };
        private object violation;

        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Метод, вызываемый при получении нового нарушителя
        public void Update(Violator violator)
        {
            // Если нарушитель движется в ту же сторону, что и пост ДПС,
            // то добавляем его в список нарушителей по направлению
            if (violator.Direction == this.Name)
            {
                violatorsByDirection[violation.Direction].Add(violator);
            }
        }
    }

    // Интерфейс для объекта, за наблюдением которого следят наблюдатели
    interface ISubject
    {
        void Attach(IObserver observer);
        void Detach(IObserver observer);
        void Notify(Violator violator);
    }

    // Объект, за изменениями которого будут следить наблюдатели
    class Road : ISubject
    {
        private List<IObserver> observers = new List<IObserver>();

        public void Attach(IObserver observer)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);
        }

        public void Detach(IObserver observer)
        {
            observers.Remove(observer);
        }

        // Метод, вызываемый при появлении нового нарушителя на дороге
        public void Notify(Violator violator)
        {
            foreach (var observer in observers)
            {
                observer.Update(violator);
            }
        }
    }

    // Пример использования
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Создаем посты ДПС
            DpsPost northPost = new DpsPost() { Name = "Север" };
            DpsPost southPost = new DpsPost() { Name = "Юг" };
            DpsPost eastPost = new DpsPost() { Name = "Восток" };
            DpsPost westPost = new DpsPost() { Name = "Запад" };

            // Создаем объекты, за изменениями которых будут следить посты ДПС
            Road road1 = new Road();
            Road road2 = new Road();

            // Подписываем посты на изменения в объектах
            road1.Attach(northPost);
            road1.Attach(southPost);
            road2.Attach(eastPost);
            road2.Attach(westPost);

            // Создаем новых нарушителей
            Violator violator1 = new Violator() { Name = "John Doe", Direction = "Север" };
            Violator violator2 = new Violator() { Name = "Jane Doe", Direction = "Юг" };

            // Уведомляем объекты об изменениях
            road1.Notify(violator1);
            road2.Notify(violator2);

            // Выводим списки нарушителей по направлениям для каждого поста ДПС
            Console.WriteLine("Нарушители по северному посту:");
            foreach (var violator in northPost.violatorsByDirection["North"])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(violator.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Нарушители по южному посту:");
            foreach (var violator in southPost.violatorsByDirection["South"])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(violator.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Нарушители по восточному посту:");
            foreach (var violator in eastPost.violatorsByDirection["East"])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(violator.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Нарушители по западному посту:");
            foreach (var violator in westPost.violatorsByDirection["West"])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(violator.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске выдаёт ошибку и ругается на строку `violatorsByDirection[violation.Direction].Add(violator);`
Текст ошибки: "object" не содержит определения "Direction", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Direction", принимающий тип "object" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить данную ошибку.

Comment: почему `object` оно? где вы хоть раз присваиваете это поле? даже если ему дать нужный тип, все равно там null. `violatorsByDirection[violator.Direction].Add(violator)`

Comment: @aepot оно прививает в строчке '''public string Direction { get; set; }'''.
У violation тип не имеет значения, я проверял. Там в любом случае будет выдаваться ошибка.

Comment: Вы сами задали тип `object` в строке `private object violation;`, и просите у него некое  свойство `Direction`. А **тип** `object` имеет это свойство? Нет, ибо это стандартный тип C#. Так может укажете верный тип `private Violator violation;`, который имеет свойство `Direction`? И да, как и сказали выше, у вас это просто пустая переменная, который вы ни разу не задали значения, нет ни единой строки `violation = ...;`, или нет `private Violator violation = new(...);`, а значит у вас в этой переменной всегда NULL, что приведет к ошибке при вызове `violator(null).Direction`. Внимательней будьте!

Comment: И в чем тогда вопрос?